# Join columns without unique keys and write down non-unique combinations in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes:

DataframeA:

```
Gene Bla Bla
AAA  xxx xxx
ABA  xxx xxx
ABA  xxx xxx
ABC  xxx xxx
```

Dataframe 2; ID field is unique, Gene is not.

```
ID Gene
123 AAA
124 AAA
125 ABA
126 ABC
```

What I want: keep the "Gene" column of the first dataframe intact, but add a new column with IDs that corresponds to the same gene

```
Gene Bla1 Bla2 ID

AAA  xxx xxx 123&124 
AAA  xxx xxx 123&124
ABA  xxx xxx 125
ABA  xxx xxx 125 
ABC  xxx xxx 126
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can aggregate DataFrame 2, combining the ID column using "groupby". You need to ensure first that ID is a string.

```py
df2['ID'] = df2['ID'].astype('str')
df_agg = df2.groupby(['Gene'])['ID'].apply('&'.join).reset_index()


# or using "agg" instead of "apply"
df_agg = df2.groupby(['Gene']).agg({'ID': '&'.join}).reset_index()
```

Then merge the aggregation.

```py
df1.merge(df_agg, on='Gene', how='left')
```

This will produce:

```py
Gene  Bla       ID
0  AAA    1  123&124
1  AAA    2  123&124
2  ABA    3      125
3  ABA    1      125
4  ABC    4      126
```